# Import VHD file to Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-compute-engine, vhd

Is there a way to create a VM instance on Google Cloud using a VHD? It looks pretty straight forward and well documented on the Azure cloud but there is no information I can find on G-Cloud.

Seems like I'm wasting my time recreating my servers on the Google Cloud and I'm quickly losing site of the value of the Google Cloud.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can bring your own image to GCE. You can follow the instruction on the [public documentation](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/images#buildingimage) on GCE. There's also this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YlcR6ZLebTM) that explains the process.

Comment: I think that's the best I'll get. It's close, just need to convert the existing VHD's to the format they support.

Answer (score 1):

VHD and VHDX virtual disk files can be converted to GCE compatible disks using steps [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/import/importing-virtual-disks).  For more sophisticated workflows the [image import workflows](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-tools/tree/master/daisy_workflows/image_import)   in the compute-image-tools repository can be useful.